# multiple form upload with image in php mysql

Tags: php

I've been trying to make this work for quite some time now. But I cant seem to make it work. I wanted to have a multiple image upload form with only using one input value

```
if (isset($_POST['multi_fresh'])) {

    $path = '';

    $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
    $classification = $_REQUEST['classification'];
    $yield = $_REQUEST['yield'];
    $price = $_REQUEST['price'];
    $farm_name = $_REQUEST['farm_name'];

    foreach ($_FILES["farm_photo"]["tmp_name"] as $key => $tmp_name) {

        $cl = $classification[$key];
        $yl = $yield[$key];
        $pr = $price[$key];
        $fn = $farm_name[$key];
        $im = $img[$key];

        if (!empty($pr)) {

            $type = $im['type'];
            $size = $im['size'];
            $name = $im['name'];
            $tmp_path = $im['tmp_name'];
            $upload = $path . "images/farm/";
            if (($type == 'image/jpg' || $type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/png' || $type == 'image/gif') && $size < 5000000) {
                $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $farmimage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $ext;
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_path, $upload . $farmimage)) {
                    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_multi_farm set user_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($user_id) . "',classification='" . mysql_real_escape_string($cl) . "',yield='" . mysql_real_escape_string($yl) . "',price='" . mysql_real_escape_string($pr) . "',farm_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($fn) . "',farm_photo='" . mysql_real_escape_string($farmimage) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
                    if ($insert) {
                        $sld_ins = "Add Sucessfully!";
                    } else {
                        $sld_err = "Check Corresponding Fields";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $inserts = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_multi_farm set user_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($user_id) . "',classification='" . mysql_real_escape_string($cl) . "',yield='" . mysql_real_escape_string($yl) . "',price='" . mysql_real_escape_string($pr) . "',farm_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($fn) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
                if ($inserts) {
                    $sld_ins = "Add Sucessfully!";
                } else {
                    $sld_err = "Check Corresponding Fields";
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i used this code but i cant get result ....

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `multiple` to your `<input>` tag and give name an array `[]` syntax:

```
<input type="file" name="imgs[]" multiple>
```

The **PHP documentation** has a guide to: [Uploading Multiple Files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

> Multiple files can be uploaded using different name for input.
>
> It is also possible to upload multiple files simultaneously and have the information organized automatically in arrays for you. To do so, you need to use the same array submission syntax in the HTML form as you do with multiple selects and checkboxes:

The example from the PHP documentation:

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

## Accesing the files in PHP

To access multiple files uploaded in PHP you use the same code as with single uploads; the built-in `$_FILES` Superglobal.

According to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) `$_FILES` is

> An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method. The structure of this array is outlined in the POST method uploads section.

You should be able to loop through this associative array like any other:

```
foreach($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
{

}
```

Comment: i used this kind but i send text box value and input file value .. i don't know how to get input file value in foreach loop.